# DOM/Javascript not returning a value, results yield NAN. Can't find the error?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a logic error and cant seem to find it.  I think I am "getting" the elements by ID correctly, but it yields NAN.  Any help with this is appreciated.
I am not sure what else I am doing wrong, any suggestions are welcome. I am new to DOM and not very familiar with Javascript.

```
var avgGrade
function calcAvg()
   {
    avgGrade = document.getElementById("finalExam") +    
document.getElementById("homework") + document.getElementById("projects");
        alert("Your average is " + avgGrade);
    document.getElementById("stuAverage").value = avgGrade;
   }

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculate average</h1>
<h3>Enter the following information and then press the <b>AVERAGE</b> button 

to calculate 
your grade.</h3>
<p>To clear the data fields, click here <b><a 

href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Refresh this page</a></b></p>
<form action="#" name="gradeInfo" id="gradeInfo">
<p>
Enter Final Exam Grade:
<input type="text" name="finalExam" id="finalExam" size="4" /><br />
Enter Homework Grade:
<input type="text" name="homework" id="homework" size="4" /><br />
Enter Projects Grade:
<input type="text" name="projects" id="projects" size="4" /><br />
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="AVERAGE" onclick="calcAvg()" />

<br /><br />
Your Average is:
<input type="text" name="stuAverage" id="stuAverage" size="4" /><br />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `node + node;` will be a _String_ equal to `node.toString() + node.toString();`. You probably wanted to add their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the value in the input field you need to write -

```
document.getElementById("finalExam").value
```

Answer (score 1):

First missing a `;` at the end of `var avgGrade`

Second you need to get values of the inputs not the inputs itself.

```
document.getElementById("homework").value
```

Third you need to convert the values from string to integer using `parseInt`

```
avgGrade = parseInt(document.getElementById("finalExam").value) +
    parseInt(document.getElementById("homework").value) +
    parseInt(document.getElementById("projects").value);
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/fs2pxpne/)

P.s. you gotta divide it to the number of grades to get the average.